# Breaking an array of elements into least number of palindromes

Tags: c++, algorithm, palindrome

How would you go about solving a problem that states:

> A given sequence of integers can be broken up into parts such that
>   each of them is a palindrome. Consider the sequence 34,45,34,56,34.
>   This can be broken up into 3 palindrome sequences with 34, 45, 34
>   constituting the first, 56 constituting the second and 34 constituting
>   the third. It can also be broken in 5 palindrome sequences each
>   containing a single number. Thus, there may be many different ways to
>   break up a given sequence into palindrome sequences. We want to
>   determine the smallest number C such that the given sequence can be
>   broken up into C palindrome sequences.

My solution does this: Find the maximum palindrome (palindrome of greatest length) of the array, take the rest of the array besides this maximum palindrome, and try to find its maximum palindrome and so on, while incrementing the count of the number of palindromes.

This is what I have so far:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#define print(arr) for(auto pos = arr.begin(); pos != arr.end(); ++pos) cout << *pos << " "; cout << endl;
typedef long long int ll;
using namespace std;

int calc(vector<ll> A, int N) {
    int i = N;
    vector <ll> t1, t2;
    while (i >= 0) {
        t1 = vector <ll> (A.begin(), A.begin()+i);
        t2 = vector <ll> (t1.rbegin(), t1.rend());
        if (t1 == t2) return i;
        i--;
    }
    return 0;

}
int main() {
    int N;
    ll x;
    cin >> N;
    vector <ll> A(N);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        cin >> x;
        A[i] = x;

    }
    int temp = calc(A,N);
    int c = 0;

    while (temp != 0) {
        A = vector <ll> (A.begin()+temp, A.end());
        N = (int)A.size();
        temp = calc(A, N);
        c++;
    }
    cout << c << endl;
}
```

However, I'm getting 3 testcases wrong. Realised later that my program outputs 4 instead of 2 for testcase: N=8, {2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1} It takes the palindromes to be {2,1,2,1,2}, {3}, {2}, {1} whereas it should be {2,1,2}, {1,2,3,2,1}. If I reverse the vector and calculate minimum answer between the two, I will get correct answer 2 for this test case but for others on Codechef I am still getting 2 testcases wrong, probably for the same reason as I am getting this wrong.

Anyway, any idea how I can improve this?

Link to problem on codechef: https://www.codechef.com/ZCOPRAC/problems/ZCO15001  Its from an ongoing competition, but the competition is only a practice contest for the Zonal Computing Olympiad held in India.

Comment: Will dynamic programming (memoization) solve it for you?

Comment: Rod Cutting Algorithm?

Comment: Why *should* it be `{2,1,2}, {1,2,3,2,1}` ? Couldn't it be `{3}, {2,2,1,1,1,2,2}` ?

Comment: @Nelxiost No, it couldn't be `{3}, {2,2,1,1,1,2,2}`. The problem is to find palindromes *in the sequence*, not palindromes which can be made with that set of numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical problem for dynamic programming. You can solve it easily with `O(N ^ 2)` complexity, where `N` is the size of input string.

First of all, you can precalculate all the palindromes with `O(N ^ 2)` complexity to answer if substring `[i, j]` is palindrome or not in `O(1)` (let it be an exercise for you).

Then you can calculate array `dp`, where `dp[i]` is the answer for substring `[0, i]`. To find `dp[i]` you need to do: `dp[i] = min(dp[i], dp[j] + 1)` for all `j` where `j < i` and substring `[j + 1, i]` is palindrome. Here you use palindromes precalculation to check if substring `[j + 1, i]` palindrome or not in `O(1)`. And `dp[0]` is `1` of course.

The answer is `dp[N - 1]`.

P.S. All indexes are 0-based.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think I understand what you mean. But btw, won't implementing a recursive solution be better? For example 3,4,3,4,5 can be first broken into 3 and 4,3,4,5 and then I try to break 4,3,4,5 and so on, while eliminating the calculation of same subsets by saving the answer in dp?

Comment: ^ DP would be a global variable then.

Comment: @AlexStone I suppose that non-recursive solutions are practically always better because of recursion overhead :)

Comment: @AlexStone `for (int j = i+1; j <= N; j++ )` here `j` should be strict lesser than `N`

Comment: My implementation is slightly different in terms of the limits. It doesn't work without it. :/ I thought Runtime error is coming because map is taking too much memory but even after removing the map and recalculating whether the subset is palindrome, I am getting Runtime Error.

Comment: Strictly less than N still gives Runtime error.. :/

Comment: @AlexStone yep, your precalculation of palindromes does not need a map . In fact you can store two arrays - one for odd palindromes, and one for even. You simply store the length of the longest palindrome with the center in the given position. It is a standard way to do such things.